# Where can I find IntelliJ documentation for different keymaps?

Tags: intellij-idea, keymapping

Background: I'm on a Mac, and the **Default** keymap on the Mac IntelliJ install is Windows (per their support).

I've been using the **Mac OS X 10.5+** keymap they recommended, which matches Mac conventions but is actually quite different from the **Default** one (not just Control vs. Command). For instance, "Delete Line" is mapped to a combination that doesn't exist on the MacBook keyboard.

The internal documentation accessed through the application sometimes refers to the Default Windows key mapping, and sometimes to the Mac key mapping, so it's not consistent, and JetBrains support said they do not have documentations for the different keymaps they provide.

So, has anyone put accurate documentation together somewhere (hopefully with a side-by-side)?

Much thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the most reliable and up to date "documentation" for keymappings will probably be the Keymap section of the settings itself. There you can browse through all commands separated by categories and view assigned shortcuts to them.

You can use dropdown to choose different schemes (Default, Default for GNOME, etc). When you have section of the commands open (for example *Editor actions*) and select different keymap from the dropdown, you see the differences between the assigned shortcuts pretty clearly.

Unfortunately side by side view of different keymaps is supported.

I don't know if this answers your question, but it is the approach that works best for me when I need to lookup some shortcuts or learn differences between let's say Windows and Linux keymaps so I thought it might be worth mentioning.